# Using Biblatex with Bibtex: undefined references

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, apa-style, texshop

I  am using TexShop (version 3.92) on Mac to write a PhD thesis. I had been using BibDesk (Version 1.6.13) for my references using the following bibliography commands:

```
\usepackage{chicago}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\bibliography{references}
```

However, the intext citations had initials as well as surname, and no comma before the date. For example:

> (Johnstone, L.R. 2016)

And I'd like to use APA style, so in text citations would appear like this:

> Johnstone (2016) states that.... or Some text here (Johnstone, 2016)
>   Some text here.

I looked at some previously answered questions on here and it appears that the use package `biblatex` should resolve the issue, however, the in text citations still include first initials and have no comma, but now the brackets are missing:

> Some text here Johnstone, L.R. 2016 some text here.

I am using the following commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear, sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Sorry if this has a simple solution, I am not a LaTex expert. I have tried a few things that people have suggested on other threads and nothing has worked as yet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

## Edit:

the bib file looks like:

```
@book{girginovparry2005, 
  Address = {{Oxon, UK}}, 
  Author = {{Girginov, V., Parry, J.}}, 
  Date-Added = {2017-10-02 18:06:52 +0000}, 
  Date-Modified = {2017-10-02 18:06:52 +0000}, 
  Publisher = {{Routledge}}, 
  Title = {{The Olympic Games explained: A student guide to the evolution of the modern Olympic Games}}, 
  Year = {{2005}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Could you post a*full* compilable code?

Comment: Thanks Bernard- what do you need- the whole source file? It is quite lengthy.

Comment: No. A minimal file showing the problem (with some bibliography items). B.t.w. did you try  loading `biblatex-chicago`?

Comment: This was using Biblatex:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear, sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

Comment: I have discovered that using the APA use package in natbib gives the right format in the reference list, but the references in the text still have the initials (ie. (Girginov, V., Parry, J., 2005) rather than (Girginov & Parry, 2005)):

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}

Comment: In the bib data the reference looks like this:

@book{girginovparry2005,
 Address = {{Oxon, UK}},
 Author = {{Girginov, V., Parry, J.}},
 Date-Added = {2017-10-02 18:06:52 +0000},
 Date-Modified = {2017-10-02 18:06:52 +0000},
 Publisher = {{Routledge}},
 Title = {{The Olympic Games explained: A student guide to the evolution of the modern Olympic Games}},
 Year = {{2005}}}
 
Is it the way that I have input the data into bibtex? Or is there a command that specifies surname only for the intext citations?

I haven't tried biblatex-chicago. Would that work?

Comment: It is supposed to reproduce the chicago style with `biblatex`, which is easier to customise than a `bst` file. The code for the `.bib` file should be added to your post.

Comment: Thanks. Is it \usepackage{biblatex-chicago}  ? the bib file is references.bib

Comment: I don't think so (I'll check in the doc), probably `\usepackage[style=chicago, ...]{biblatex}`.

Comment: Chicago style (as implemented by `biblatex-chicago`) and APA style are quite different styles. Are you sure you need to follow either of the two to the letter? Or would you also be OK with `style=authoryear` and a few modifications? By default `biblatex` does not include first name initials *unless* they are needed to disambiguate names ('Johnstone, Laura' from 'Johnstone, Anne', for example). You can use `\parencite` to get citations in brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors in your bib entry, for example do you not need to double the brackets and authors are divided by `and`, not a comma!

Please see the following complete MWE (with package `filecontents` I added the corrected bib entry and called style `apa` with `biblatex` and `biber`. Used `article` to get citings and bibliography on one page):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{girginovparry2005, 
  Address = {Oxon, UK}, 
  Author = {Girginov, V. and Parry, J.}, 
  Date-Added = {2017-10-02 18:06:52 +0000}, 
  Date-Modified = {2017-10-02 18:06:52 +0000}, 
  Publisher = {Routledge}, 
  Title = {The Olympic Games explained: A student guide to the evolution of the modern Olympic Games}, 
  Year = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{article}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber, % bibtex <=============================================
  style=apa, % authoryear <=============================================
  natbib, % <===========================================================
  sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % ========================================

\begin{document}

text \cite{girginovparry2005}  text \citet{girginovparry2005} 
text \citep{girginovparry2005} text \parencite{girginovparry2005} 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]